# Help Insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a simple trigger but I cannot figure out why it's not insert Account List Item records. Here is the code.

```
Trigger Eisai_createAcctListItem on Affiliation_vod__c (before insert){

    Set<String> affToAcctSet = new Set<String>();
    List<Account_List_vod__c> existingAcctList = new List<Account_List_vod__c>();
    List<Account_List_Item_vod__c> toInsertAcctListItem = new List<Account_List_Item_vod__c>();

    for(Affiliation_vod__c newAff: Trigger.New)
    {
        if(newAff.Parent_vod__c = false)
        {
            affToAcctSet.add(newAff.To_Account_Value__c);
        }   
    }

    existingAcctList = [SELECT Id, Name_Substring__c FROM Account_List_vod__c WHERE Name_Substring__c IN :affToAcctSet];

    for(Account_List_vod__c allAcctList: existingAcctList){
        for(Affiliation_vod__c affRec : Trigger.New)
        {
            Account_List_Item_vod__c AccListItem = new Account_List_Item_vod__c(
                                      Account_List_vod__c = allAcctList.Id,
                                      Account_vod__c = affRec.From_Account_vod__c
            );
            toInsertAcctListItem.add(AccListItem);
        }
    }

    Database.insert(toInsertAcctListItem,false));

}//end of trigger
```

Basically, what I want to happen is, after child affiliation record was inserted, the trigger should find the `Account List record (Master)` where `Name_Substring__c` is in the Set of named `'affToAcctSet'` then will create `Account List Item record (Details)`

Comment: So... what are you seeing for `totalRecordsInserted` and `totalRecordsFailed`?

Comment: no, sorry I just coppied that from my class :(

Comment: Put in more system debugs, and figure out what list is failing, it also looks like you can use Maps here to improve the overall function of the trigger

Comment: @EricSSH I'm just new in apex coding and Map collections is confusing on my end :(

Comment: @Noiram Take the time and figure them out, but either way you need to put in more System.debugs and figure out what part of your code is failing, also what is `To_Account_Value__c`?

Comment: @EricSSH To_Account_Value__c is a formula field to get the String Name of Account instead of returning the Id of Account.

Comment: One thing to change is `newAff.Parent_vod__c = false` (which is always false) to this `newAff.Parent_vod__c == false` or this `!newAff.Parent_vod__c` (which is true when the value is false and false when the value is true).

Comment: this is the _nth_ OP I've seen with field names suffixed by `vod__c` - what does the `vod` stand for? In my line of business, it would be video-on-demand but I don't think that's it here.  Curious

Comment: @KeithC Thanks, I overlooked that. when I made is newAff.Parent_vod__c == false. it worked, but I am still worried not using map yet. How can I convert it using map

Comment: Yeah the double nested loop at the end looks wrong. I've posted my best guess making use of a map as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may not fix your issue but it is an issue, I bet you `affToAcctSet` is null because per your comment so with that being said this will need to be an After Insert trigger, you will also have to look into Keiths answer.  So as I said put in `System.debug('affToAcctSet is null?' + affToAcctSet);`

To add, I don't know your structure but if you move this to an After Insert/Update ..? You can use the id of the account, rather than relying on a String to do your query

Comment: Hi @EricSSH, I cannot use the Account id in my query for existingAcctList because there is no look up field for the Account, only Account List Name and Name_SubString (Formula to get the Account name). I already changed it to After insert event and set newAff.Parent_vod__c == false (It's working) but I think it would be better to use MAP? not sure yet

Comment: That would need to be another question after you tried a few things,  your data structure does seem kind of wonky which would be a job for another day..  You will have to key your Map<String, account...>? 
Take a look at http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/01/06/fun-with-salesforce-collections/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure of the relationships but something like this may be what you are looking for:

```
Trigger Eisai_createAcctListItem on Affiliation_vod__c (before insert) {

    Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
    for (Affiliation_vod__c a: Trigger.New) {
        if (a.Parent_vod__c == false) {
            names.add(a.To_Account_Value__c);
        }   
    }

    // Only works if only 1 record per Name_Substring__c
    Map<String, Id> m = new Map<String, Id>();
    for (Account_List_vod__c> a : [
            SELECT Id, Name_Substring__c
            FROM Account_List_vod__c
            WHERE Name_Substring__c IN :names
            ]) {
        m.put(a.Name_Substring__c, a.Id);
    }

    List<Account_List_Item_vod__c> inserts = new List<Account_List_Item_vod__c>();
    for (Affiliation_vod__c a : Trigger.New) {
        if (a.Parent_vod__c == false) {
            Id id = m.get(a.To_Account_Value__c);
            if (id != null) {
                inserts.add(new Account_List_Item_vod__c(
                        Account_List_vod__c = id,
                        Account_vod__c = a.From_Account_vod__c
                        ));
            }
        }
    }
    Database.insert(inserts, false);
}
```

Comment: `To_Account_Value__c` is a formula field you make this an after insert @Noiram you should be set